# Getting Build error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload' in "......" " for angular application

Tags: angular, typescript

I wanted to use file upload feature in angular for newly created angular application but getting this build error

"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload' in '...../component.ts' "

I have been using file upload feature in other application without any issue. My new project is using copied code and configuration from older and successfully deployed application.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution.

My latest application is using ng2-file-upload version 1.4 (see package.json) and all previous version was using version 1.3. So there are two way to fix this issue

1. Either downgrade to 1.3 and use like this
   import { FileUploader, FileItem, FileUploaderOptions } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';
2. or if you want to continue using 1.4 then import in component like below
   import { FileUploader,  FileItem, FileUploaderOptions  } from 'ng2-file-upload';